# how to retrieve data via ajax only if there is new json data?

Tags: jquery

the field I am populating is a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="history"></table>
```

the jquery-ajax looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

        function fetchComments()
        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/members/comment/fetch/',
                    dataType: "json",
                    timeout: 100,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        $.each(data, function(i, data){
                             $(".history").append("<tr><td>" + data.member_id + "</td><td>" + data.comment + "</td></tr>");
                        })                          
                    }
            });
        }

        function clear()
        {
            $(".history").html('');
            fetchComments();

        }
        setInterval(clear, 1000);

    });
</script>
```

the page that is fetching the json (/members/comment/fetch) looks like this:

```
[{"member_id":"2","comment":"horses--"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"kkk"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"sarmen22kkkkkkkkkkkkkj"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"sarmen22kkkkkkkkkkkkkj"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"sarmen22kk"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"sarmen22"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"sarmen"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"lklklk"},{"member_id":"1","comment":"this is admin"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"kkk"},{"member_id":"1","comment":"this is admin 2"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"kkk"}]
```

the way this json is being created is by reading all the rows in mysql and outputting into json format. the problem i am having is that the setinterval is re-requesting the json every second and the table that gets populated is acting very jittery and doesn't populate the data smoothly. How can i do write it so that the table gets populated smoothly. This is a simple little chat app that I'm creating.

ps: its also making the page refresh (in some way) so if there was a long table of data and i scrolled down, the refresh makes the page go back up.

Comment: You could introduce some kind of cursor, something that tells which comments you have and from which comment on you want to get the new ones. This can be as simple as a simple counter.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by not wiping everything out and recreating the table data on every setInterval iteration, and instead just appending new data only to the table.

Comment: Can you post your table structure and query? You will need to pass back the key to your most recent table entry in the Ajax request

Comment: You could use a timestamp on the table. So when you add a new comment you insert the time it was made. Then on your request you send the time you last updated and only get comments later than that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few quick ways you could use.
Maybe store the success data in a variable, and check if it has changed before re-writing the table.

ThatSteveGuy's answer would be the most correct way, however, you would probably need to return a primary key from the database to implement it.

```
var lastData = "";
...
success: function(data) 
{
   if (data != lastData)
   {
     lastData = data;
     $(".history").html('');
     ... (foreach data populate the table)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I would use the `setTimeout()` function **once ajax request has loaded** (with or without error) instead of using the `setInterval()` function, which does not take into account possible connection problems/delays.

Also, I would make the query return the timestamp of each comment, the latest of which you can send back later at your ajax request, to retrieve comments posted after that time. If you don't have this data in your table, I would definitely add that as `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. This could also be useful for your history:

> **Somebody:** Hi, what's up?
>  (sent on Oct. 11, 2012 at 6.48 AM)